# pop3 IIS 6 , allow remote connections

Tags: iis-6, pop3

I'm using a EC2 windows 2003 instance. I managed to install pop3 and i can connect to it locally (using outlook express with the remote desktop) and the server address is the machine name. I also added MX record on the DNS (mail.mydomain.com) but still i can't connect to the pop3 server remotely using either mail.mydomain.com or even the server IP.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is your firewall, have you opened port 110 on your firewall?

Comment: yes, port 110 is opened on both server and EC2 security settings.